# Precision Matlab and Python (numpy)

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, precision

I'm converting a Matlab script to Python and I am getting different results in the 10**-4 order.

In matlab:

```
f_mean=f_mean+nanmean(f); 
f = f - nanmean(f);

f_t  = gradient(f);
f_tt = gradient(f_t);

if n_loop==1
  theta = atan2( sum(f.*f_tt), sum(f.^2) );
end

theta = -2.2011167e+03
```

In Python:

```
f_mean = f_mean + np.nanmean(vel)

vel = vel - np.nanmean(vel)

firstDerivative = np.gradient(vel)
secondDerivative = np.gradient(firstDerivative)


if numberLoop == 1:
    theta = np.arctan2(np.sum(vel * secondDerivative),
                       np.sum([vel**2]))
```

Although first and secondDerivative give the same results in Python and Matlab, f_mean is slightly different: -0.0066412 (Matlab) and -0.0066414 (Python); and so theta: -0.4126186 (M) and -0.4124718 (P). It is a small difference, but in the end leads to different results in my scripts.

I know some people asked about this difference, but always regarding std, which I get, but not regarding mean values. I wonder why it is.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You've shown the code, which is great, but you haven't provided the input array `f_mean`, so we can't run the code to reproduce the result.

Comment: In the Python code, is `f_mean` initially a numpy array?  If so, what is `f_mean.dtype`?

Comment: thing is the array is huge, over one million data. but vel would start with [-0.042 -0.028 -0.038 -0.013 -0.026 -0.031 -0.0560 ...]

Comment: f_mean.dtype = float64

Comment: According to wikipedia numpy uses [pairwise summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation) which on a huge array such as yours should have better accuracy than the naive method. Don't know what matlab does, though.

Comment: In Python, you could try `np.nanmean(vel, dtype=np.longdouble)`, but that won't make a difference if you are on Windows, where `longdouble` is the same as `double`.

Answer (score 1):

One possible source of the initial difference you describe (between means) could be numpy's [use](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/3685) of [pairwise summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation) which on large arrays will typically be appreciably more accurate than the naive method:

```
a = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (10**6,))
a = np.r_[-a, a]
# so the sum should be zero

a.sum()
# 7.815970093361102e-14

# use cumsum to get naive summation:
a.cumsum()[-1]
# -1.3716805469243809e-11
```

**Edit (thanks @sascha):** for the last word and as a ["provably exact"](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/393090/) reference you could use `math.fsum`:

```
import math
math.fsum(a)
# 0.0
```

Don't have matlab, so can't check what they are doing.

Comment: And just for fun: ```math.fsum(a.tolist())``` (even more precise, but probably much slower).

Comment: @sascha Neat! It is rather slow, but funnily enough seems faster than Python sum...